# minted: remove space between caption and frame in float environments

Tags: captions, minted, newfloat

I am using `minted` with the `newfloat` option to typeset code listings in float environments. Unfortunately, the caption in such a case has a large distance to the source code area:

```
\begin{listing}
\caption{This is a test}
\label{lst:motivation:test}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,frame=lines]{python}
from time import localtime

activities = {8: 'Sleeping',
              9: 'Commuting',
              17: 'Working',
              18: 'Commuting',
              20: 'Eating',
              22: 'Resting' }

time_now = localtime()
hour = time_now.tm_hour

for activity_time in sorted(activities.keys()):
    if hour < activity_time:
        print activities[activity_time]
        break
else:
    print 'UNKNOWN, AFK OR SLEEPING!'
\end{minted}
\end{listing}

This is a test for \autoref{lst:motivation:test} auto references.
```

Results in:

[image: too much space]

My suspicion is that there is a margin around the frame from the `minted` environment but I cannot find options to control this. The only working hack that I found is to add a negative space to the caption, which sounds ugly:

```
\captionsetup[listing]{position=above,skip=-10pt}
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Why is that ugly?